# Why is my app crashing on opening the database?

Tags: android, database

everyone, I'm a completely new in android app development, and was trying my hand at using database to store some strings, but every time I try to open my database, my app crashes with the following error message:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLETASKS": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLETASKS(_idinteger primary key autoincrementtasktext not null);

Full code and error log follows:

```
package org.example.tasklist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

HelperMethods localhelpermethods;
OpenHelper localopenhelper;
SQLiteDatabase localdatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Context localcontext = getApplicationContext();

    localopenhelper = new OpenHelper(localcontext);
    localhelpermethods = new HelperMethods(localcontext);

    final ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>           (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,al);
    listView1.setAdapter(aa);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        { 
           localhelpermethods.open_database();
           String task = editText1.getText().toString();
           localhelpermethods.add_task(task);
           aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
     });

}


@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return true;
 }    
}
```

my OpenHelper class.
    package org.example.tasklist;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{


  public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TASKS.db";
  public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
  public final String DATABASE_TABLE = "TASKS";

  //Columns in the table.
  public final String KEY_TASK = "task";
  public final String KEY_ID = "_id";

  private static Context context;

  public OpenHelper(Context context)
  {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
  }

  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
  {
      database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + "integer primary key autoincrement" 
  + KEY_TASK + "text not null);");
  }

  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldversion, int newversion)
  {
     if(newversion > oldversion)
     {
         database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE );
         onCreate(database);
     }
  }
}
```

My HelperMethods class.

```
package org.example.tasklist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class HelperMethods
{
    OpenHelper OH;
    SQLiteDatabase task_database;
    ArrayList<String> return_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static Context localcontext;

    public HelperMethods(Context context)
    {
        HelperMethods.localcontext = context;
        OH = new OpenHelper(localcontext);
    }

    public HelperMethods open_database() throws SQLException
    {
        task_database = OH.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllTasks()
    { 
        String[] columns = new String[] {OH.KEY_TASK};
        Cursor cursor = task_database.query(OH.DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            return_list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OH.KEY_TASK)));
        }
        return return_list;     
    }

    public void add_task(String task)
    {
        OH.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(OH.KEY_TASK, task);
        task_database.insert(OH.KEY_TASK, null, cv);
        OH.close();
    }

}
```

logcat error output.

```
05-02 16:08:50.990: E/SQLiteLog(2590): (1) near "TABLETASKS": syntax error
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590): Process: org.example.tasklist, PID: 2590
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLETASKS": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLETASKS(_idinteger primary key autoincrementtasktext not null);
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at org.example.tasklist.OpenHelper.onCreate(OpenHelper.java:29)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at org.example.tasklist.HelperMethods.open_database(HelperMethods.java:26)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at org.example.tasklist.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
05-02 16:08:51.020: E/AndroidRuntime(2590):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have to add some space between your table row name and the datatype to identify it ,which you have missed.

Just change your create table query as below:

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement " + KEY_TASK + " text not null); ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:
_idinteger primary key autoincrementtasktext not null

should be 
_idinteger primary key autoincrement tasktext not null

Note the space

Comment: For sure that typo prevented your database to load correctly and made your app crash. If it is indeed the case, please accept that answer! If not, please make my culture.

Comment: This looks like a great answer, but I removed my previous upvote when you urged the poster to accept it less than a half hour after you contributed it.

Comment: it worked thank you very much Syl OR and Chris Stratton.